# How do I output into a file in subdirectory?

Tags: c++, fstream, stringstream

This is not a duplicate. I'm trying to print some output to a file in a subdirectory (in this case to a file /stuff/output_1.txt) but it doesn't seem to create any new file. The code executes but no file is created, nor any subdirectory called /stuff. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
  int out = 1;
  stringstream fname;
  fstream f;
  fname << "./stuff/output" << "_" << out << ".txt";
  f.open(fname.str().c_str(), ios_base::out);
  f << "hello" << "\t";
  f << endl;
  f.close();
}
```

When I instead use the line

```
fname << "output" << "_" << out << ".txt";
```

It creates a file called output_1.txt in the current directory so the rest of the code clearly works. What is going wrong?

I'm on macOS so the "/" should be correct instead of the "\" used on Windows, no?

Comment: You have to create the subdirectory first, using `mkdir`. A file can only be created in a directory that already exists.

Comment: Is there a directory called stuff?

Comment: Brilliant, thank you so much. I thought I had tried that but looks like I hadn't. :)

Comment: btw since C++11 there is an overload that takes a `std::string`, ie you can do `f.open(fname.str() , ios_base::out);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> no file is created, nor any subdirectory

You are using `fstream` which expects the path to exist. If you are referencing a directory and it doesn't exist, then it will fail, because either you have to create the directory before you run your program, or you have to use `mkdir()` to create it.

You can check with `f.is_open()` if your stream could be opened.

```
f.open(fname.str().c_str(), ios_base::out);
if (f.is_open())
{
    f << "hello" << "\t";
    f << endl;
    f.close();
}
else
    std::cerr << "Unable to open " << fname;
```

Answer (score 0):

> nor any subdirectory called ./stuff

Why did you expect `fstream` to create subdirectories for you ? You have to do that yourself. I got the same behaviour when testing it on my machine, and the simple solution was to do a `mkdir stuff`. After that, the file got correctly created. But I think it's weird no runtime error is thrown. It's not good (especially for beginners) that `fstream` jsut silently does nothing when the subdirectory is not existing.